# Changing 'theorem' to 'Theorem' while using \cleveref{}

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, cleveref

I am using the package cleveref. So whenever I write `\cref{label}`, it shows theorem {theorem_number}.

The 't' in theorem is small (so the result is 'theorem'). I want to write it as 'Theorem'.

Which referencing package should I use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an initial capital letter in references, just use `\Cref{label}` (with a capital `C`).

Answer (score 2):

The cleveref documentation describes this in section 7.1 Capitalising All Cross-Reference Names.  See this link [documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)

Comment: I read the pdf. I am struggling with the syntax. I tried \usepackage{cleveref}{capitalize} and \usepackage{cleveref}[capitalize]. But I am getting syntax errors in both cases.

Comment: Ah.  You should add an MWE to your question.

Comment: What is MWE ? Can you explain ?

Comment: @learning_math `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}`